# Create Dictionary Field From Two Pandas Fields

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Let's say I have a data frame like:

```
time    action    player    ...[other fields]
----------------------------------------------
10:00   Buy       A
10:00   Hold      B
09:45   Sell      A
09:45   Buy       B
09:45   Hold      A
09:30   Hold      A
```

I am able to create a list of actions with `df.groupby('time)['action'].apply(list)`

I want to create a field that aggregates on `time` and creates a dictionary from `action`/`player`.

So expected output is:

```
 time    action    ...[other fields]
----------------------------------------------
10:00   {A:Buy,B:Hold}
09:45   {A:[Sell,Hold],B:Buy}
09:30   {A:Hold}
```

Maybe something like `df.groupby('time)['action'].apply(dict,player=action)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close...just `set_index` to player that way when you `groupby`, and `agg(dict)` you have the appropriate keys for your dict.

```
df.set_index('player').groupby('time')['action'].agg(dict)

time
09:30                          {'A': 'Hold'}
09:45    {'A': ['Sell', 'Hold'], 'B': 'Buy'}
10:00              {'A': 'Buy', 'B': 'Hold'}
```

Comment: Worked for me! Not sure why though... would it be too much to ask for a brief explanation as to how/why this happens? Is it because Pandas recognizes the index as the key when creating a dictionary field??

Comment: @Samcd, That is correct. when you `agg` with `dict` pandas will use the index as the key and the column as the value. It is similar to using `pd.Series.to_dict()` which will use the index of the frame as the key.